# iOS: Make searching/ filtering through an Array faster

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a an NSMutableArray that I search through using the following code (that I got through an online tutorial by raywenderlich). I am hoping someone can tell me a way to make searching through the NSMutablearray faster? My array has over 2000 submissions and it is a tad slow. Hopefully I can make it faster. My filterList is what I show in a tableview and searchList contains all of my data.

```
    @property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mFilterList;
    @property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mSearchList;



  - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.string contains[c] %@ || "
                                   @"SELF.title contains[c] %@ ",
                                   searchText, searchText];
    NSArray *tempArray =
     [self.mSearchList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    self.mFilterList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
    }
```

Comment: That is an expensive search and there isn't much you can do to improve its performance against an array. You could delay performing the search until the user has stopped typing for a few seconds so that you don't perform so many searches.

Comment: Can you suggest a faster search that isn't as expensive?

Comment: Use Instruments to focus on what is slow about this. For one thing, the `removeAllObjects` is a complete waste! I'm sure you can do better than this. First of all, what I would do make a completely different array that contains the `string` and `title` of all the objects, so that you are not doing an "or" search and so that you are not drilling down into a property every time. And I would use a simple block instead of the predicate. But only Instruments can tell you what to tweak.

Comment: Write your own code to enumerate the array and return matching values. It should be faster than using a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for substrings contained in a field is very slow. It would be faster if you searched for exact matches.

You could speed up substring searching if you broke the things you were searching into keywords and built an index table of keywords in the table you were searching. Database engines like SQL are much better at this than NSArray because they include things like keyed indexes that make searching faster.